# Best strategy for managing audio instances to allow cross-fades, etc

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, audio-player

I'm working on an iOS application that works with different pieces of audio.  Each piece of audio is tied to a separate button (similar to the kind of functionality you'd see in a soundboard app).

In a simple soundboard application, you've got an instance of a player object (AVAudioPlayer or an AVAudioEngine player node) that gets fired whenever a button is pressed.

If you push `buttonOne`, then `sound1` plays.

If you push `buttonOne` again while `sound1` is still playing, then the current instance is interrupted and "replaced" with a new instance of `sound1` that starts over at the beginning.

If you push `buttonOne`, THEN push `buttonTwo` before `sound1` is finished, the instance of `sound1` is interrupted and replaced with `sound2`, again, played from the beginning.

Suppose you're trying to enable cross-fading between the two sounds.  You can just create two player instances, load the first sound into `player1` and the second into `player2`, and cross fade between them.

Building on that, suppose you're trying to allow different combinations of sounds to play at the same time.  Either the idea that a large number of sounds (maybe the whole soundboard) can all play without interrupting each other.  Or, perhaps, the ability to have multiple sounds playing at the same time, e.g. `sound1` is a music bed, and `sound2`...`soundXX` are sound effects that should be able to play over the music bed without interrupting it.

QUESTIONS: what is the best design strategy for managing your player instances in this situation?  Suppose you have a 5 x 5 grid of buttons in your soundboard.  If, hypothetically, you should be able to play all 25 sounds at the same time, would that require you to init 25 player instances at setup? (this seems very anti-DRY and not particularly efficient).  Or is there some way to dynamically manage the number of instances you need (maybe with a lazy variable?) so that additional instances are only generated as needed, e.g. when you have x number of sounds playing and you start another, an additional instance is generated to contain the newly added sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the best design strategy for managing instances of AVAudioPlayer in this situation

None. You should be using AVAudioEngine. That's exactly what it is, a sound board / patch kit.

> Or is there some way to dynamically manage the number of instances you need

If I have 25 ordered instances of a thing where one possibility is no instance at all, that sounds like an array of Optionals.

Comment: Thx-I have revised to reflect your suggestion, but that's not really what I'm asking.  Whether it's AVAudioPlayer player objects or AVAudioEngine nodes, the question is what's the best way to manage the instances.  In your iOS 12 book (I have both! ;) you set up 2 player instances, 2 file vars, 2 url vars, etc. and what I'm asking is -- if I have to manage potentially N number of player instances at a given moment, what's the best strategy?  It sounds like if there's (N-1) sounds playing and I add another, I'm looking at dynamically generating playerN, fileN, urlN for the last instance?

Comment: Put another way, if I've got 25 buttons on my sound board, am I better off just having an AVAudioEngine node assigned to each?  That doesn't seem very efficient but if it's intended to be a patch bay kit, maybe that's the easiest way to handle it?

Comment: So the question is really about “Or is there some way to dynamically manage the number of instances you need”? Do you mean like an Optional? (This button either has a sound associated with it or it doesn’t.)

Comment: Yes, I think that's the question.  AVAudioEngine is new to me, AVAudioPlayer not so much, but it's the same issue from a programming standpoint -- a) it seems strange from a programming perspective to declare potentially 25 instances of audio variables (one per button) when most of the time I'm unlikely to need more than 2 (basic crossfade between 2 playing tracks) or 4-5 (music bed plus, say, some number of one-off hits), but b) I don't want to impose an arbitrary "polyphony" limit by only having, say, 8 instances available for use.

Comment: The other way I'm thinking about this is how table cells are queued/dequeued as they scroll off the screen -- is there an analogy here to having X number of player instances available to the application, and a particular button's output is assigned to the next available player instance, or whichever one was most recently "destroyed"?

Comment: That’s why I suggested Optionals. There is no inefficiency to keeping 1 player node and 24 nil references.